# Disassembling the "assembly" and "disassembly" tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Here's a very tricky ambiguous tag. We have [assembly](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/assembly) (x16) and [disassembly](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disassembly) (x8). Both are a perfect mix between:

- Assembler code, architectures and whatnot
- Computer building

---

#### Proposal:

I suggest we retag those that fit the latter into [computer-building](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-building) and create a synonym [computer-assembly](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-assembly) to fit this better. Leave the rest unchanged (even the tag wiki mentions machine code).

Vote up for *yay*, vote down for *nay*.

Comment: some items did not apply to computer building specific. http://superuser.com/questions/187254/how-prevalent-are-old-x64-processors-lacking-the-cmpxchg16b-instruction , http://superuser.com/questions/158945/how-to-assign-strong-name-to-an-assembly , http://superuser.com/questions/111587/linux-and-assembly-blocking , http://superuser.com/questions/88110/what-is-the-maximum-addressible-memory , http://superuser.com/questions/159163/windows-assembly-folder-typical-size-aka-gac

Comment: We also have the  word [Repair] added word [laptop-repair] arbirtray use of the word [Replacement] and [connection] and others. and as you know I am not complaining. just looking.

Comment: The combination [system-building] which I either spelled wrong or doesnt come up in search. duhh, because it is already merged over. and the artistically created [Hardware-Combination] and [Hardware-selection] combo tags :-)

Comment: We can make system-building a synonym of computer-building.

Comment: you know my opinion. we make [Building] and [computer] and [System], and let them use them together. We then describe a computer, and decribe a system, and decribe Building.  and let them use them in combo with software or anything else.  I Agree completly (voted up) but there has to be another way.

Comment: Yeah I know you like to have it differently, but we have to use what we have, and what the majority agrees with ;)

Comment: When it comes to Follow & find, in this one, when building computers, or being a computer builder, or wanting to search for computer building tips, being able to follow or just push the [computer-build] or [computer-building] tag would work great.

Comment: I agree, leave the assembly/disassembly tags for their true meanings (instruction set encoding/decoding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affected questions have now been **`MOV`** ed into [computer-building](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-building), where they should have been all the time.

Tag wiki for [disassembly](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disassembly) created.

Comment: Wouldn't [assembler] or [assembly-language] and [disassembler] be less ambigous?

Comment: @ArneStenström True. They can be renamed to that if necessary.

Comment: +1 `[assembly-language]` sounds like a good idea @ArneStenström